# How to Transform / Reverse SVG Icon When it is Used as a Click Icon in Accordion Menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, svg

I'm trying to create accordion menu with jQuery and SVG.
Then, I attempt to use SVG Arrow Icon as a click button, but 
I can not make the Icon rotate flexibly.
Here is my [Codepen](https://codepen.io/Honoka007/pen/bGNxyMB).

```html
//SVG Arrow Icon
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
    viewBox="0 0 48 48" enable-background="new 0 0 48 48" width="30" height="30" class="svg_arrow">
<rect class="st0" width="30" height="30"/>
<path class="st1" d="M16,28l7.5-7.5c0.9-0.9,2.2-0.9,3.1,0L34,28" stroke="#2dac9a"/>
</svg>
```

```css
//SVG CSS
svg{
  fill: #2dac9a;
  position: absolute;
  top: 15px;
  right: 10px;
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}

.tr{
  transform: rotate(0deg);
}
```

```
$('.faq_accordion').on('click', function () {
  $(this).children().eq(1).slideToggle(300);
  $(this).children('.faq_li').toggleClass('b');
  $(this).children('.faq_li').find('svg')[0].setAttribute('class', 'tr'); //does not work...
  $(".faq_accordion .faq_answer").not($(this).children().eq(1)).slideUp(300);
});
```

When I click the SVG Arrow Icon, the 'setAttribute' Method works,
but I do not know how to reverse position when I click it once again.
It seems to me that 'toggleAttribute' method also does not work...(I tried it.)
I appreciate if you teach me the effective way.
I 'm sorry if this question is already solved in another section.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

```
.tr{
  transform: rotate(0deg);
} // revome this

svg{
     fill: #2dac9a;
     position: absolute;
     top: 15px;
     right: 10px;
     transform: rotate(180deg);
     transition: transform 300ms; // Add this
}

.b svg {
    transform: rotate(0deg); 
} // Add this
```

Comment: this wont work as expected,  try opening this scenario, open this fist one, without closing first one, open the second one and then close the second one. Icons  are toggled.

Comment: Thank you for your comment.<br>As you pointed out, I noticed that when I clicked first button and clicked second button, the fist button is still toggled. <br> I will try to improve and  utilize toggleClass method.